# Scheduling commands by system inactivity

Tags: command-line, scheduling

So `cron` or `at` can schedule our commands to run at  the exact time we need them to, but can we schedule commands to run when systems are **inactive**?

Something like:

```
echo "some_commands" | when 'cpu < 15%'
```

Comment: you have to be more specific: what is the purpose of some_command?

Comment: from your question it is not clear whether you talk about seti@home or some delayed maintenance script.

Comment: a script to run when the pc isn't too busy....

Comment: are you being intentionally thick? a one-off thing? a daemon? something that grabs every free cpu cycle it can? something io heavy?

Comment: no hop, im not trying to be thick nor am I trying to be rude. I'm going assume my question is clear enough as the 3 answers recieved are all spot-on.

Comment: This is a good question @Stefan. At my previous job we ran alot of load-dependent Oracle batch jobs using DBMS_JOB, and it's common to only run jobs when the load falls below a particular level. I often wished we could do this well using cron, but we only came up with hackish solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmmm... I don't think so... but what you could do is cron a script to run like every 5 minutes and check the *load average* to see if it's acceptably low. I wouldn't check the *current* because you could get the cpu in between 2 really high peaks. This is just thoughts on what I'd do to accomplish this, but there might be a better way.

Comment: Keep in mind that `uptime` reports load averages for three different intervals (last minute, last five minutes and last fifteen minutes).  In general load average is only the average number of items in the run queue during that time interval.  On some systems (Linux in particular) processes in "D" state are counted as runnable.  So a system with processes waiting on a slow (or missing) NFS server can appear to have a large load average that has nothing to do with real load on the system.

Answer (score 6):

[Fcron](http://fcron.free.fr/description.php) has a lot of additional features over common cronds. For example:

- set the max system load average value under which the job should be run

(quote from the Homepage)

Thus, you could use fcron to setup what you want.

Answer (score 4):

On many systems the at daemon is configured such that the `batch` command will run a command when the system drops below a certain load.  However, this may not give you the fine grained control you are looking for.

Comment: From 'man batch' on my Fedora 14 system: batch   executes commands when system  load  levels  permit;  in  other
               words,  when  the  load  average  drops below 0.8, or the value
               specified in the invocation of atd.

Answer (score 2):

A friend of mine [posted about this problem](http://blogs.igalia.com/aperez/2010/08/dmon-process-monitoring-with-style/) some days ago. He talks about this tool [Dmon](http://gitorious.org/dmon). I did not test it, but it sounds great.